# Assiging Integer value using JSTL set

Tags: java, jstl

I just realize I can't set Integer value using JSTL set tag. I checked other post but didn't find related issue.

My JSTL code looks like

```
<c:set var="endIndex" 
       value="${fn:length(offeredService) - fn:length(serviceHistory) - 1} lt 0 ? ${fn:length(offeredService)} : ${fn:length(offeredService) - fn:length(serviceHistory) - 1}"/>
```

And error I am getting is

```
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert -1 lt 0 ? 0 : -1 of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Integer
```

Whaat I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you just need to extend the braces so that the ternary operator actually evaluates?

```
<c:set var="endIndex" 
    value="${
        (fn:length(offeredService) - fn:length(serviceHistory) - 1) < 0 ? 
        fn:length(offeredService)
        : fn:length(offeredService) - fn:length(serviceHistory) - 1
    }
"/>
```

As it is, the ternary operator is outside of an execution block so it is just treated like text.

Comment: This time it says javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert 0
     of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Integer on <c:forEach begin="${fn:length(serviceHistory)}" end="${endIndex}" var="index">

Comment: Maybe try end="${Integer.valueOf(endIndex)}".

Comment: Now I have  <c:set var="endIndex" value="${fn:length(offeredService) == 0 ? 4 : (fn:length(offeredService) - 1) }"/>  <c:forEach begin="${fn:length(serviceHistory)}" end="${Integer.valueOf(endIndex)}" var="index">  But I am getting TypeError: obj is undefined error in Firebug console.